# batch convert audio files in vlc

Tags: itunes, audio, homebrew, vlc

I am trying to add some files to iTunes: some .wma files which it will not import, and some .m4a files which it will import but not play because it does not know bitrate or duration.

I have tried the following:

- converting with VLC: the files all play fine in VLC but I can only convert them one at a time, despite being able to give multiple files as input for transcoding, which implies batch conversion should be possible.
- using ffmpeg to convert the files. This gives the error:

  ```
  dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libx264.142.dylib
    Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg
    Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
      /opt/local/lib/libx264.148.dylib/libx264.142.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20`
  ```

when I try to reinstall ffmpeg in homebrew, building from source, as suggested in [this question on github](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/27866) I get the error message `Error: SHA256 mismatch`.

There must be a simple way to batch convert files, either with vlc or command-line tools. How?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried VLC for batch conversion, or CLI alternatives, but searching on Google returns [Mediahuman](http://www.mediahuman.com/audio-converter/) on first place. It's a free app and it can work with .wma.

I haven't used it -install with care, watch for uninvited crapware.

I've used [fre:ac](http://www.freac.org/) with great success for batch processing. It's open source and free.

> It currently works with MP3, MP4/M4A, WMA, Small Vorbis iconVorbis,
>   Small FLAC iconFLAC, AAC, WAV and Bonk formats.